# How can I enforce user path to always include user id for core user profile page in durpal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a Drupal 7 website with an online community. I want user profile to always include UID so users can more easily copy and share link to their profile.

Logged in users should be redirected to site.com/user/UID from site.com/user

Comment: Provide one you would like to share with me and I will test the UID.

Answer (score 1):

you can hook in to preprocess_page() in template.php or in your custom module

then get arg(0) and arg(1) . if arg(0) is equal to 'user' and arg(1) is empty redirect the user to any url you want

user/uid is already exist in drupal so you just need to do the following:

```
global $user;
drupal_goto('/user/'.$user->uid);
```